# Problem Android Studio - failed to resolve com.android.support appcompat-v7 29

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I'm trying to start a course with Android Studio 2.2.1, but when I create a new project I come upon the error message:

> failed to resolve com.android.support appcompat-v7 29

Also my Mainactivity.java gives me the error:

> Method does not override method from superclass.

I've tried to add the Maven URL, but with no luck.

When I try to rebuild the project I get:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. Could not resolve
>   all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'. Could not
>   find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
>   Versions that do not match:
>   26.0.0-alpha1
>   25.3.1
>   25.3.0
>   25.2.0
>   25.1.1
>   + 31 more Required by: DemoAppTwo:app:unspecified

Does anybody know a solution for this, so that I can start learning to code in android please?
Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
KevinDP

Comment: `support` library is deprecated and the last version was 28. Now android provide `AndroidX` library. Please try to upgrade your **Android Studio** and migrate your project to **AndroidX**

Answer (score 1):

That is not a version of the support library that exists - the last version was 28 (and it has since been [replaced](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)).

You should download the latest version of Android Studio (currently 3.5.3) from the [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/studio) and start again with that.  It will create the new project for you with the correct dependencies.